# <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.4.2" /> neccessary?

Tags: security, customization

Hello fellow WordPressers

Today, I realized that most WordPress sites have this small footprint saying:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.4.2" />
```

where it indicates what 
"system" have made this current page. Now three questions popped into my mind:

1. If I remove this line, what is the disadvantages?
2. If I leave this line alone, what is the advantages?
3. By indicating the WordPress version, won't it be easier for (evil)robots to search for vulnerabilities, and try to exploit my websites?

I hope someone here can clear my mind.

Comment: The meta doesn't give you any advantages or disadvantages. As long as you keep your site updated with latest security fixes. You should be fine.

Comment: Ok, I'll remove it - since I don't really need it. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Nothing (you will ruin some web stats that look at it, but you probably son't care about that)
2. Nothing
3. No. Evil people don't care what is the value otherwise the easiest security measure would have been to change it instead of actually upgrading anything.

Comment: Thank you, I'll remove the meta tag. It's not needed, and in this case: less code, better code!